# Xamarin Studio btouch unsupported type for Fields : NSUuid

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, binding, xamarin.ios

I trying to bind an obj-c library from the manufacturer Sensoro to Xamarin.ios on my mac but I've been stuck on a strange build error as advertised in the question subject. I used sharpie 3 to scan the header files. What's strange to me is that NSUuid is a class type from Xamarin's own Foundation namespace so it should be supported so I don't know why the build process complains about it. Here's the ApiDefinition.cs

```
using System;
using CoreBluetooth;
using CoreLocation;
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;

namespace SensoroBeaconKit
{
    [Static]
    //[Verify (ConstantsInterfaceAssociation)]
    partial interface Constants
    {
        // extern NSString *const SBKBeaconInRangeStatusUpdatedNotification;
        [Field ("SBKBeaconInRangeStatusUpdatedNotification", "__Internal")]
        NSString SBKBeaconInRangeStatusUpdatedNotification { get; }

        // extern NSUuid * SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID;
        [Field ("SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID", "__Internal")]
        NSUuid SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID { get; }

        // extern NSString *const SBKErrorDomain;
        [Field ("SBKErrorDomain", "__Internal")]
        NSString SBKErrorDomain { get; }

        // extern NSString *const SBKBeaconBaseSettingsTransmitPowerKey;
        [Field ("SBKBeaconBaseSettingsTransmitPowerKey", "__Internal")]
        NSString SBKBeaconBaseSettingsTransmitPowerKey { get; }

        // extern NSString *const SBKBeaconBaseSettingsAdvertisingIntervalKey;
        [Field ("SBKBeaconBaseSettingsAdvertisingIntervalKey", "__Internal")]
        NSString SBKBeaconBaseSettingsAdvertisingIntervalKey { get; }

        // extern NSString *const SBKBeaconBaseSettingsEnergySavingModeKey;
        [Field ("SBKBeaconBaseSettingsEnergySavingModeKey", "__Internal")]
        NSString SBKBeaconBaseSettingsEnergySavingModeKey { get; }

        // extern NSString *const SBKBeaconBaseSettingsMeasuredPowerKey;
        [Field ("SBKBeaconBaseSettingsMeasuredPowerKey", "__Internal")]
        NSString SBKBeaconBaseSettingsMeasuredPowerKey { get; }

        // extern NSString *const SBKBeaconSensorSettingsTemperatureSamplingIntervalKey;
        [Field ("SBKBeaconSensorSettingsTemperatureSamplingIntervalKey", "__Internal")]
        NSString SBKBeaconSensorSettingsTemperatureSamplingIntervalKey { get; }

        // extern NSString *const SBKBeaconSensorSettingsLightSamplingIntervalKey;
        [Field ("SBKBeaconSensorSettingsLightSamplingIntervalKey", "__Internal")]
        NSString SBKBeaconSensorSettingsLightSamplingIntervalKey { get; }

        // extern NSString *const SBKBeaconSensorSettingsAccelerometerSensitivityKey;
        [Field ("SBKBeaconSensorSettingsAccelerometerSensitivityKey", "__Internal")]
        NSString SBKBeaconSensorSettingsAccelerometerSensitivityKey { get; }
    }

    // @interface SBKBeaconID : NSObject <NSCopying>
    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    interface SBKBeaconID : INSCopying
    {
        // +(instancetype)beaconIDWithProximityUUID:(NSUuid *)proximityUUID;
        [Static]
        [Export ("beaconIDWithProximityUUID:")]
        SBKBeaconID BeaconIDWithProximityUUID (NSUuid proximityUUID);

        // +(instancetype)beaconIDWithProximityUUID:(NSUuid *)proximityUUID major:(CLBeaconMajorValue)major;
        [Static]
        [Export ("beaconIDWithProximityUUID:major:")]
        SBKBeaconID BeaconIDWithProximityUUID (NSUuid proximityUUID, ushort major);

        // +(instancetype)beaconIDWithProximityUUID:(NSUuid *)proximityUUID major:(CLBeaconMajorValue)major minor:(CLBeaconMinorValue)minor;
        [Static]
        [Export ("beaconIDWithProximityUUID:major:minor:")]
        SBKBeaconID BeaconIDWithProximityUUID (NSUuid proximityUUID, ushort major, ushort minor);

        // -(BOOL)isEqualToBeaconID:(SBKBeaconID *)aBeaconID;
        [Export ("isEqualToBeaconID:")]
        bool IsEqualToBeaconID (SBKBeaconID aBeaconID);

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSUuid * proximityUUID;
        [Export ("proximityUUID")]
        NSUuid ProximityUUID { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * major;
        [Export ("major")]
        NSNumber Major { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * minor;
        [Export ("minor")]
        NSNumber Minor { get; }

        // -(CLBeaconRegion *)CLBeaconRegion;
        [Export ("CLBeaconRegion")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty)]
        CLBeaconRegion CLBeaconRegion { get; }

        // +(instancetype)beaconIDFromCLBeaconRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region;
        [Static]
        [Export ("beaconIDFromCLBeaconRegion:")]
        SBKBeaconID BeaconIDFromCLBeaconRegion (CLBeaconRegion region);

        // -(NSString *)stringRepresentation;
        [Export ("stringRepresentation")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty)]
        string StringRepresentation { get; }

        // +(instancetype)beaconIDWithString:(NSString *)string;
        [Static]
        [Export ("beaconIDWithString:")]
        SBKBeaconID BeaconIDWithString (string @string);
    }

    // typedef void (^SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)(NSError *);
    delegate void SBKBeaconCompletionBlock (NSError arg0);

    // @interface SBKBeacon : NSObject
    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    interface SBKBeacon
    {
        [Wrap ("WeakDelegate")]
        [NullAllowed]
        SBKBeaconDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

        // @property (readwrite, nonatomic, weak) id<SBKBeaconDelegate> _Nullable delegate;
        [NullAllowed, Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Weak)]
        NSObject WeakDelegate { get; set; }

        // @property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) SBKBeaconID * beaconID;
        [Export ("beaconID", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
        SBKBeaconID BeaconID { get; }

        // @property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString * serialNumber;
        [Export ("serialNumber")]
        string SerialNumber { get; }

        // @property (readonly, assign, nonatomic) BOOL inRange;
        [Export ("inRange")]
        bool InRange { get; }

        // @property (assign, readwrite, nonatomic) NSInteger inRangeMinimumRssiWhileEntering;
        [Export ("inRangeMinimumRssiWhileEntering")]
        nint InRangeMinimumRssiWhileEntering { get; set; }

        // @property (assign, readwrite, nonatomic) NSInteger inRangeMinimumRssiWhileLeaving;
        [Export ("inRangeMinimumRssiWhileLeaving")]
        nint InRangeMinimumRssiWhileLeaving { get; set; }

        // @property (readonly, assign, nonatomic) NSInteger rssi;
        [Export ("rssi")]
        nint Rssi { get; }

        // @property (readonly, assign, nonatomic) CLProximity proximity;
        [Export ("proximity", ArgumentSemantic.Assign)]
        CLProximity Proximity { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationAccuracy accuracy;
        [Export ("accuracy")]
        double Accuracy { get; }

        // @property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSNumber * batteryLevel;
        [Export ("batteryLevel", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
        NSNumber BatteryLevel { get; }

        // @property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString * hardwareModelName;
        [Export ("hardwareModelName")]
        string HardwareModelName { get; }

        // @property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString * firmwareVersion;
        [Export ("firmwareVersion")]
        string FirmwareVersion { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) SBKBeaconWorkMode workModel;
        [Export ("workModel")]
        SBKBeaconWorkMode WorkModel { get; }

        // -(void)connectWithCompletion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("connectWithCompletion:")]
        void ConnectWithCompletion (SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(void)disconnect;
        [Export ("disconnect")]
        void Disconnect ();

        // -(SBKBeaconConnectionStatus)connectionStatus;
        [Export ("connectionStatus")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty)]
        SBKBeaconConnectionStatus ConnectionStatus { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSDictionary * baseSettings;
        [Export ("baseSettings")]
        NSDictionary BaseSettings { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSDictionary * sensorSettings;
        [Export ("sensorSettings")]
        NSDictionary SensorSettings { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) SBKBeaconSecureBroadcastInterval secureBroadcastInterval;
        [Export ("secureBroadcastInterval")]
        SBKBeaconSecureBroadcastInterval SecureBroadcastInterval { get; }

        // -(BOOL)writeProximityUUID:(NSUuid *)proximityUUID completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("writeProximityUUID:completion:")]
        bool WriteProximityUUID (NSUuid proximityUUID, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)writeMajor:(NSNumber *)major minor:(NSNumber *)minor completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("writeMajor:minor:completion:")]
        bool WriteMajor (NSNumber major, NSNumber minor, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)writeBaseSettings:(NSDictionary *)settings completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("writeBaseSettings:completion:")]
        bool WriteBaseSettings (NSDictionary settings, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)writeSensorSettings:(NSDictionary *)settings completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("writeSensorSettings:completion:")]
        bool WriteSensorSettings (NSDictionary settings, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)resetToFactorySettingsWithCompletion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("resetToFactorySettingsWithCompletion:")]
        bool ResetToFactorySettingsWithCompletion (SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)writeSecureBroadcastInterval:(SBKBeaconSecureBroadcastInterval)interval completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("writeSecureBroadcastInterval:completion:")]
        bool WriteSecureBroadcastInterval (SBKBeaconSecureBroadcastInterval interval, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)writeBroadcastKey:(NSString *)key completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("writeBroadcastKey:completion:")]
        bool WriteBroadcastKey (string key, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)clearBroadcastKeyWithCompletion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("clearBroadcastKeyWithCompletion:")]
        bool ClearBroadcastKeyWithCompletion (SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)disableiBeaconWithCompletion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("disableiBeaconWithCompletion:")]
        bool DisableiBeaconWithCompletion (SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)enableiBeaconWithCompletion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("enableiBeaconWithCompletion:")]
        bool EnableiBeaconWithCompletion (SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)disableAliBeaconWithCompletion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("disableAliBeaconWithCompletion:")]
        bool DisableAliBeaconWithCompletion (SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)enableAliBeaconWithCompletion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("enableAliBeaconWithCompletion:")]
        bool EnableAliBeaconWithCompletion (SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)disableEnhanceBroadcastWithCompletion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("disableEnhanceBroadcastWithCompletion:")]
        bool DisableEnhanceBroadcastWithCompletion (SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)enableEnhanceBroadcastWithCompletion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("enableEnhanceBroadcastWithCompletion:")]
        bool EnableEnhanceBroadcastWithCompletion (SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)flashLightWithCommand:(UInt8)command repeat:(UInt8)repeatCount completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("flashLightWithCommand:repeat:completion:")]
        bool FlashLightWithCommand (byte command, byte repeatCount, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) SBKBeaconWritePermissionStatus writePermissionStatus;
        [Export ("writePermissionStatus")]
        SBKBeaconWritePermissionStatus WritePermissionStatus { get; }

        // -(BOOL)requireWritePermissionWithPassword:(NSString *)password completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("requireWritePermissionWithPassword:completion:")]
        bool RequireWritePermissionWithPassword (string password, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)updateWritePassword:(NSString *)password completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("updateWritePassword:completion:")]
        bool UpdateWritePassword (string password, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)clearWritePasswordWithCompletion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("clearWritePasswordWithCompletion:")]
        bool ClearWritePasswordWithCompletion (SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(SBKBeaconEnergySavingMode)availableEnergySavingMode;
        [Export ("availableEnergySavingMode")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty)]
        SBKBeaconEnergySavingMode AvailableEnergySavingMode { get; }

        // -(BOOL)reloadSensorDataWithCompletion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("reloadSensorDataWithCompletion:")]
        bool ReloadSensorDataWithCompletion (SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)isTemperatureSensorAvailable;
        [Export ("isTemperatureSensorAvailable")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty)]
        bool IsTemperatureSensorAvailable { get; }

        // -(BOOL)isLightSensorAvailable;
        [Export ("isLightSensorAvailable")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty)]
        bool IsLightSensorAvailable { get; }

        // -(BOOL)isAccelerometerAvailable;
        [Export ("isAccelerometerAvailable")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty)]
        bool IsAccelerometerAvailable { get; }

        // -(BOOL)isBeacon;
        [Export ("isBeacon")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty)]
        bool IsBeacon { get; }

        // -(BOOL)isSensor;
        [Export ("isSensor")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty)]
        bool IsSensor { get; }

        // @property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSNumber * temperature;
        [Export ("temperature", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
        NSNumber Temperature { get; }

        // @property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSNumber * light;
        [Export ("light", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
        NSNumber Light { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * broadcastTransmitPower;
        [Export ("broadcastTransmitPower")]
        NSNumber BroadcastTransmitPower { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * broadcastInterval;
        [Export ("broadcastInterval")]
        NSNumber BroadcastInterval { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * inEnergySaving;
        [Export ("inEnergySaving")]
        NSNumber InEnergySaving { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * aliBeacon;
        [Export ("aliBeacon")]
        NSNumber AliBeacon { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * enhanceBroadcast;
        [Export ("enhanceBroadcast")]
        NSNumber EnhanceBroadcast { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * eddystoneEnabled;
        [Export ("eddystoneEnabled")]
        NSNumber EddystoneEnabled { get; }

        // @property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSNumber * accelerometerCount;
        [Export ("accelerometerCount", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
        NSNumber AccelerometerCount { get; }

        // @property (readonly, getter = isMoving, copy, nonatomic) NSNumber * moving;
        [Export ("moving", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
        NSNumber Moving { [Bind ("isMoving")] get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * shakeToLightOn;
        [Export ("shakeToLightOn")]
        NSNumber ShakeToLightOn { get; }

        // -(BOOL)resetAccelerometerCountWithCompletion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("resetAccelerometerCountWithCompletion:")]
        bool ResetAccelerometerCountWithCompletion (SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)writeShakeToLightOnState:(BOOL)state completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("writeShakeToLightOnState:completion:")]
        bool WriteShakeToLightOnState (bool state, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic, strong) CBPeripheral * assignedPeripheral;
        [Export ("assignedPeripheral", ArgumentSemantic.Strong)]
        CBPeripheral AssignedPeripheral { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * eddystoneUIDEnabled;
        [Export ("eddystoneUIDEnabled")]
        NSNumber EddystoneUIDEnabled { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * eddystoneURLEnabled;
        [Export ("eddystoneURLEnabled")]
        NSNumber EddystoneURLEnabled { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * eddystoneTLMEnabled;
        [Export ("eddystoneTLMEnabled")]
        NSNumber EddystoneTLMEnabled { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSData * eddystoneNID;
        [Export ("eddystoneNID")]
        NSData EddystoneNID { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSData * eddystoneBID;
        [Export ("eddystoneBID")]
        NSData EddystoneBID { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * eddystoneTLMInterval;
        [Export ("eddystoneTLMInterval")]
        NSNumber EddystoneTLMInterval { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSString * eddystoneUrl;
        [Export ("eddystoneUrl")]
        string EddystoneUrl { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * eddystoneBatteryVoltage;
        [Export ("eddystoneBatteryVoltage")]
        NSNumber EddystoneBatteryVoltage { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * eddystonePduCount;
        [Export ("eddystonePduCount")]
        NSNumber EddystonePduCount { get; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSNumber * eddystoneWorkedTime;
        [Export ("eddystoneWorkedTime")]
        NSNumber EddystoneWorkedTime { get; }

        // -(BOOL)writeEddystoneUrl:(NSString *)url completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("writeEddystoneUrl:completion:")]
        bool WriteEddystoneUrl (string url, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)eddystonePackage:(EddystonePackageType)package enable:(BOOL)enable completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("eddystonePackage:enable:completion:")]
        bool EddystonePackage (EddystonePackageType package, bool enable, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)writeEddystoneTLMInterval:(EddystoneTLMInterval)interval completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("writeEddystoneTLMInterval:completion:")]
        bool WriteEddystoneTLMInterval (EddystoneTLMInterval interval, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)writeEddystoneNID:(NSString *)nidString completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("writeEddystoneNID:completion:")]
        bool WriteEddystoneNID (string nidString, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);

        // -(BOOL)writeEddystoneBID:(NSString *)bidString completion:(SBKBeaconCompletionBlock)completion;
        [Export ("writeEddystoneBID:completion:")]
        bool WriteEddystoneBID (string bidString, SBKBeaconCompletionBlock completion);
    }

    // @protocol SBKBeaconDelegate <NSObject>
    [Protocol, Model]
    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    interface SBKBeaconDelegate
    {
        // @optional -(void)sensoroBeaconDidConnect:(SBKBeacon *)beacon;
        [Export ("sensoroBeaconDidConnect:")]
        void SensoroBeaconDidConnect (SBKBeacon beacon);

        // @optional -(void)sensoroBeaconRequirePassword:(SBKBeacon *)beacon;
        [Export ("sensoroBeaconRequirePassword:")]
        void SensoroBeaconRequirePassword (SBKBeacon beacon);

        // @optional -(void)sensoroBeaconDidDisconnect:(SBKBeacon *)beacon error:(NSError *)error;
        [Export ("sensoroBeaconDidDisconnect:error:")]
        void SensoroBeaconDidDisconnect (SBKBeacon beacon, NSError error);

        // @optional -(void)sensoroBeacon:(SBKBeacon *)beacon didUpdateSensorSetting:(NSDictionary *)settings;
        [Export ("sensoroBeacon:didUpdateSensorSetting:")]
        void SensoroBeaconDidUpdateSensorSetting (SBKBeacon beacon, NSDictionary settings);

        // @optional -(void)sensoroBeacon:(SBKBeacon *)beacon didUpdateRSSI:(NSInteger)rssi;
        [Export ("sensoroBeacon:didUpdateRSSI:")]
        void SensoroBeaconDidUpdateRSSI (SBKBeacon beacon, nint rssi);

        // @optional -(void)sensoroBeacon:(SBKBeacon *)beacon didUpdateTemperatureData:(NSNumber *)temperature;
        [Export ("sensoroBeacon:didUpdateTemperatureData:")]
        void SensoroBeaconDidUpdateTemperatureData (SBKBeacon beacon, NSNumber temperature);

        // @optional -(void)sensoroBeacon:(SBKBeacon *)beacon didUpdateLightData:(NSNumber *)light;
        [Export ("sensoroBeacon:didUpdateLightData:")]
        void SensoroBeaconDidUpdateLightData (SBKBeacon beacon, NSNumber light);

        // @optional -(void)sensoroBeacon:(SBKBeacon *)beacon didUpdateAccelerometerCount:(NSNumber *)accelerometerCount;
        [Export ("sensoroBeacon:didUpdateAccelerometerCount:")]
        void SensoroBeaconDidUpdateAccelerometerCount (SBKBeacon beacon, NSNumber accelerometerCount);

        // @optional -(void)sensoroBeacon:(SBKBeacon *)beacon didUpdateMovingState:(NSNumber *)isMoving;
        [Export ("sensoroBeacon:didUpdateMovingState:")]
        void SensoroBeaconDidUpdateMovingState (SBKBeacon beacon, NSNumber isMoving);
    }

    // typedef void (^SBKBeaconWatcher)(SBKBeacon *, SBKBeacon_Action);
    delegate void SBKBeaconWatcher (SBKBeacon arg0, SBKBeacon_Action arg1);

    // @interface SBKBeaconManager : NSObject
    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    interface SBKBeaconManager
    {
        // +(SBKBeaconManager *)sharedInstance;
        [Static]
        [Export ("sharedInstance")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty)]
        SBKBeaconManager SharedInstance { get; }

        [Wrap ("WeakDelegate")]
        [NullAllowed]
        SBKBeaconManagerDelegate Delegate { get; set; }

        // @property (nonatomic, weak) id<SBKBeaconManagerDelegate> _Nullable delegate;
        [NullAllowed, Export ("delegate", ArgumentSemantic.Weak)]
        NSObject WeakDelegate { get; set; }

        // -(void)requestAlwaysAuthorization;
        [Export ("requestAlwaysAuthorization")]
        void RequestAlwaysAuthorization ();

        // -(void)requestWhenInUseAuthorization;
        [Export ("requestWhenInUseAuthorization")]
        void RequestWhenInUseAuthorization ();

        // -(void)startRangingBeaconsWithID:(SBKBeaconID *)beaconID wakeUpApplication:(BOOL)wakeUpApplication;
        [Export ("startRangingBeaconsWithID:wakeUpApplication:")]
        void StartRangingBeaconsWithID (SBKBeaconID beaconID, bool wakeUpApplication);

        // -(void)stopRangingBeaconsWithID:(SBKBeaconID *)beaconID;
        [Export ("stopRangingBeaconsWithID:")]
        void StopRangingBeaconsWithID (SBKBeaconID beaconID);

        // -(void)stopRangingAllBeacons;
        [Export ("stopRangingAllBeacons")]
        void StopRangingAllBeacons ();

        // -(BOOL)addBroadcastKey:(NSString *)secretInfo;
        [Export ("addBroadcastKey:")]
        bool AddBroadcastKey (string secretInfo);

        // -(void)registerBeaconAppearWatcher:(NSString *)identifier type:(u_int8_t)type watcher:(SBKBeaconWatcher)watcher;
        [Export ("registerBeaconAppearWatcher:type:watcher:")]
        void RegisterBeaconAppearWatcher (string identifier, byte type, SBKBeaconWatcher watcher);

        // -(NSSet *)rangedBeaconIDs;
        [Export ("rangedBeaconIDs")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty)]
        NSSet RangedBeaconIDs { get; }

        // -(SBKBeacon *)beaconWithID:(SBKBeaconID *)beaconID;
        [Export ("beaconWithID:")]
        SBKBeacon BeaconWithID (SBKBeaconID beaconID);

        // -(SBKBeacon *)beaconWithCLBeacon:(CLBeacon *)beacon;
        [Export ("beaconWithCLBeacon:")]
        SBKBeacon BeaconWithCLBeacon (CLBeacon beacon);

        // -(NSArray *)beaconsInRange;
        [Export ("beaconsInRange")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty), Verify (StronglyTypedNSArray)]
        NSObject[] BeaconsInRange { get; }

        // -(NSArray *)allBeacons;
        [Export ("allBeacons")]
        //[Verify (MethodToProperty), Verify (StronglyTypedNSArray)]
        NSObject[] AllBeacons { get; }

        // -(void)disableBLEPowerAlert;
        [Export ("disableBLEPowerAlert")]
        void DisableBLEPowerAlert ();

        // @property (readwrite, nonatomic) NSTimeInterval outOfRangeDelay;
        [Export ("outOfRangeDelay")]
        double OutOfRangeDelay { get; set; }

        // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSString * version;
        [Export ("version")]
        string Version { get; }

        // @property (readwrite, nonatomic) BOOL duplicateKeyBLE;
        [Export ("duplicateKeyBLE")]
        bool DuplicateKeyBLE { get; set; }

        // -(void)setDebugModeActive:(BOOL)active;
        [Export ("setDebugModeActive:")]
        void SetDebugModeActive (bool active);
    }

    // @protocol SBKBeaconManagerDelegate <NSObject>
    [Protocol, Model]
    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    interface SBKBeaconManagerDelegate
    {
        // @optional -(void)beaconManager:(SBKBeaconManager *)beaconManager didRangeNewBeacon:(SBKBeacon *)beacon;
        [Export ("beaconManager:didRangeNewBeacon:")]
        void DidRangeNewBeacon (SBKBeaconManager beaconManager, SBKBeacon beacon);

        // @optional -(void)beaconManager:(SBKBeaconManager *)beaconManager beaconDidGone:(SBKBeacon *)beacon;
        [Export ("beaconManager:beaconDidGone:")]
        void BeaconDidGone (SBKBeaconManager beaconManager, SBKBeacon beacon);

        // @optional -(void)beaconManager:(SBKBeaconManager *)beaconManager scanDidFinishWithBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons;
        [Export ("beaconManager:scanDidFinishWithBeacons:")]
        //[Verify (StronglyTypedNSArray)]
        void ScanDidFinishWithBeacons (SBKBeaconManager beaconManager, NSObject[] beacons);

        // @optional -(void)beaconManager:(SBKBeaconManager *)beaconManager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(SBKBeaconID *)region;
        [Export ("beaconManager:didRangeBeacons:inRegion:")]
        //[Verify (StronglyTypedNSArray)]
        void DidRangeBeacons (SBKBeaconManager beaconManager, NSObject[] beacons, SBKBeaconID region);

        // @optional -(void)beaconManager:(SBKBeaconManager *)beaconManager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status;
        [Export ("beaconManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:")]
        void DidChangeAuthorizationStatus (SBKBeaconManager beaconManager, CLAuthorizationStatus status);

        // @optional -(void)beaconManager:(SBKBeaconManager *)beaconManager didDetermineState:(SBKRegionState)state forRegion:(SBKBeaconID *)region;
        [Export ("beaconManager:didDetermineState:forRegion:")]
        void DidDetermineState (SBKBeaconManager beaconManager, SBKRegionState state, SBKBeaconID region);
    }

    // @interface Cloud (SBKBeaconManager)
    [Category]
    [BaseType (typeof(SBKBeaconManager))]
    interface SBKBeaconManager_Cloud
    {
        // -(void)setCloudServiceEnable:(BOOL)set;
        [Export ("setCloudServiceEnable:")]
        void SetCloudServiceEnable (bool set);
    }

    // @interface SBKUnitConvertHelper : NSObject
    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    interface SBKUnitConvertHelper
    {
        // +(float)rangeRadiusOfBeacon:(SBKBeacon *)beacon;
        [Static]
        [Export ("rangeRadiusOfBeacon:")]
        float RangeRadiusOfBeacon (SBKBeacon beacon);

        // +(short)transmitPowerToRawValue:(SBKBeacon *)beacon;
        [Static]
        [Export ("transmitPowerToRawValue:")]
        short TransmitPowerToRawValue (SBKBeacon beacon);

        // +(float)frequencyToRawValue:(SBKBeacon *)beacon;
        [Static]
        [Export ("frequencyToRawValue:")]
        float FrequencyToRawValue (SBKBeacon beacon);

        // +(NSString *)transmitPowerToString:(SBKBeacon *)beacon;
        [Static]
        [Export ("transmitPowerToString:")]
        string TransmitPowerToString (SBKBeacon beacon);

        // +(NSString *)frequencyToString:(SBKBeacon *)beacon;
        [Static]
        [Export ("frequencyToString:")]
        string FrequencyToString (SBKBeacon beacon);

        // +(BOOL)isMicroTX:(SBKBeacon *)beacon;
        [Static]
        [Export ("isMicroTX:")]
        bool IsMicroTX (SBKBeacon beacon);

        // +(NSData *)urlToEddystoneEncodeURL:(NSString *)url;
        [Static]
        [Export ("urlToEddystoneEncodeURL:")]
        NSData UrlToEddystoneEncodeURL (string url);
    }
}
```

Comment: turns out I may need to use btouch-native instead of just btouch since monotouch is now out of date. But how on earth do I configure Xamarin Studio to use the native version of the tool ?

Comment: I used the commandline version of btouch-native, still says that NSUuid is not a supported type... argh!

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out this to make the error go away:

```
// extern NSUuid * SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID;
[Field ("SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID", "__Internal")]
NSUuid SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID { get; }
```

Then [file a bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) to get the problem solved.

Comment: I bound this lib also, I changed the NSUuid to an IntPtr and then added a helper to convert that to a NSUuid... I added an answer that shows what I did in order to make this and allow you to obtain the guid constant.

Answer (score 1):

I have bound that library and you can convert the `NSUuid` to an `IntPtr` as `NSUuid` is not supported as a [Field](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries/#Binding_Fields) Attribute.

**1st)** Review the header def:

```
extern NSUUID * SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID;
```

Since it is a pointer to an NSUuid you can use an IntPtr instead and those are supported as Field Attributes.

**2nd)** Change the `NSUuid` to an `IntPtr` in your `ApiDefinition.cs`:

```
//// extern NSUuid * SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID;
[Field("SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID", "__Internal")]
IntPtr SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID { get; }
```

**3nd)** Create an `.cs` file (i.e. [Extra.cs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-c-libraries/Images/Screen_Shot_2012-02-08_at_3.33.07_PM.png)) to hold a helper property that converts the `IntPtr` to a `NSUuid`:

```
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;

namespace Sushi.Sensoro.BeaconKit
{

    public class ConstantsEx
    {
        static NSUuid _SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID;
        static public NSUuid SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID
        {
            get
            {
                if (_SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID == null)
                {
                    var libUUID = Runtime.GetNSObject(Constants.SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID) as NSUuid;
                    _SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID = new NSUuid(libUUID.GetBytes());
                }
                return _SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var _SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID = Sushi.Sensoro.BeaconKit.ConstantsEx.SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID;
Console.WriteLine(_SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID);
```

**Note:** This constant should be "23A01AF0-232A-4518-9C0E-323FB773F5EF" (at least with version 4.1.3 of the Sensoro SDK)